# hive shows Null value

Tags: hive

I have query related to hive that Cygnus create external table in hive and it creates table in default database. But when I fetch data from hive using below query it shows me NULL value:

```
hive> select * from hadoop_abcdx002ftestsinkx002fx0052oom1_x0052oom_row
    > ;
```

> OK NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
>   NULL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
>   NULL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
>   NULL
>
> Time taken: 1.495 seconds, Fetched: 12 row(s)

Can anyone please help me on how to proceed further with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just run the below command:

Show create table hadoop_abcdx002ftestsinkx002fx0052oom1_x0052oom_row;

Check the location and Go to the location path where the underlying csv file is present.

check if you have data in it.

Comment: Thanks for reply,this command shows me location as LOCATION 'hdfs://master.hadoop.lan:9000/user/hadoop/abcd/testsink/Room1_Room'
It shows me content of file and further file location which gives me no output?

Comment: Can you try loading your data using :
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/Room1_Room.csv' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE hadoop_abcdx002ftestsinkx002fx0052oom1_x0052oom_row;

Comment: Thanks for the reply.The problem was in file format.I Changed it from json to csv format.